# How to set fixed passcode to app?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've made a new app and I'd like to put it on the market but I want to put it in beta. When the app is started, I'd like for a dialog box or edit text box to appear and ask for a code. I'd like the code to be set as "1234". When the user enters "1234", I'd like for the app to start normally everytime it is started. I want this so I can do an invite-only beta. My app has a splash screen setup.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this codes

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="1234"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

Or try below codes from Activity. Such as

```
  EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
            etPassword.setText("1234");
```